# DateTimeStyles and WhiteSpaces characters

Tags: c#, datetime, whitespace

I'm tring to understand the uses of DateTimeStyles inside `DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider,DateTimeStyles)` Method

Basically `DateTimeStyles` is filled like `AllowInnerWhite`,`AllowLeadingWhite`and others that deal with "white-space characters"

According to msdn.microsoft these fields are used to Ignore the White-Spaces When it Come into string that we want to Convert to `Datetime` Value

I tried some thing like

```
        var TestDate = "\"t\"31/07/1998 12:00:00";

        // Try To parse with en-GB culture

        var result1 = DateTime.Parse(TestDate, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"),DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

but I got an Exception

For Beginner I don't find any examples that demonstrate the idea of White-Spaces and These these fields deal with White-Spaces.

For me I think Escaping characters one of the White-Spaces in C# that is why is used to see what will happen!

Can anyone help me with some examples about these two points White-Spaces,DateTimeStyles with White-Spaces

Comment: You have literal `"` characters in your test string, these are not white-space so are not ignored - hence the exception.  `"\t31/07/1998 12:00:00"` would parse .

Comment: Use trim to remove the white spaces from the end : var result1 = DateTime.Parse(TestDate.Trim(), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"),DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
        Console.WriteLine(result1);

Comment: No repro once the input is fixed to actually contain tabs and spaces

Answer (score 3):

As others in the comments have already mentioned, you have a literal `"` in your expression, which is *not* white-space but an invalid character. This is why your value won't parse.

---

To address your other question:

> Could anyone help me with some examples about DateTimeStyles with White-Spaces.

Apparently, the `Allow*` values are only relevant for `(Try)ParseExact`, not for `(Try)Parse` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv2.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2)):

> The `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` methods can use any of the `DateTimeStyles` values. However, if none of the Allow* values is selected, the input string must have exactly the same white-space characters as the format string.

Example:

```
string s = "\t 1998-07-31 12:00:00Z "; // has leading and trailing whitespace
DateTime dt;

// Prints True: (Try)Parse does not care.
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse(s, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt));

// Prints False: (Try)ParseExact does not like whitespace.
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "u", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt));

// Prints True: (Try)ParseExact accepts whitespace, if we tell it to.
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "u", null, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dt));
```

Comment: `Parse` also works. The OP's string uses escaping incorrectly so it end with double quotes instead of a tab. `DateTime.Parse(" \t31/07/1998 12:00:00 ", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"),DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces)` doesn't throw

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I know. My answer addresses the point *"Could anyone help me with some examples about these tow points White-Spaces,DateTimeStyles with White-Spaces*". I've made that clearer now and also addressed the typo.

Comment: I see what you mean: I tried with `DateTimeStyles.None` and got no exception

Comment: @Heinzi - If i use Parse method with `var s = "\t 1998-07-31 12:00:00Z " ` and with out any DateTime Style, the pares method also work. Why I would use dateTimeStyles (AllowWhiteSpaces) if there is no problem with parsing Operation ?! In General Why I would ignore the spaces in string ?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `\`, you are telling the compiler to refer to what ever come after as a literal charterer.
That why in your case, you tried to parse a date timme string that starts with a `"t"`.

You can parse `"31/07/1998 12:00:00"`